# How to not display common border between two adjacent divs?

Tags: html, css

I have two divs with same border style, have different heights and are back to back to each other. I want the common border between them not to display. How can this be done in html and css?

[image]

Comment: what browsers do you need to support?

Comment: Seconded. Would you mind making a jsfiddle? This could be solved a number of ways depending on how you're laying these out right now.

Comment: One div can have a border right and the next can have have border-left of zero.The common border is the border-right.You can remove the border right too.

Comment: @vector all modern browsers starting from IE7+.

Comment: @Zach They are not laid out yet. If there are many ways, then pick the one which works best in all modern browsers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A lot of people have suggested getting the smaller `div` to overlap the larger one and setting the left border to the same color as the background color. The problem with this is that **you will get a 1px gap at the two spots where the `div` borders overlap**:

http://jsfiddle.net/RWz4A/

In order to avoid this, you can explicitly remove the left border, and have a non-transparent background.

**HTML**

```
<div id="one"></div><div id="two"></div>​
```

**CSS**

```
#one, #two {
    width: 100px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    display: inline-block;
}
#one {
    height: 200px;
}
#two {
    height: 100px;

    position: relative;
    left: -1px;
    background: white;
    border-left: none;
}​
```

**[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/RWz4A/1/)**

**Edit:**

As thirdender mentioned, you can also use `margin-left` instead of a combination of `position` and `left`. This may be a better option for you depending on your previous styling and how the elements are arranged (probably better in most cases if `margin-left` is not already set).

Zach Shipley also made a good point about browser support for `display: inline-block` and added the following CSS:

```
*display: inline;
zoom: 1;
vertical-align: bottom;
```

Comment: Instead of `position: relative; left: -1px;`, how about just `margin-left: -1px;`?

Comment: I'd just make one change here. @Tony_Henrich mentioned he needed IE7 support. So just add some code to emulate `display: inline-block`. jsfiddle edit (added a body background to demonstrate that your solution is robust): http://jsfiddle.net/RWz4A/3/

Comment: Thanks for pointing those issues out. I've updated the answer with both of your suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

position the smaller div on the right to overlap the border of the left div,
and make sure it doesn have border-left set

Answer (score 0):

set `border-right: ... border-left: ...`

Comment: Just setting the left and right borders will give you a 1 pixel gap where the borders intersect: http://jsfiddle.net/RWz4A/

Comment: maybe this will be some kind of shortcut but u can do this like that http://jsfiddle.net/M89PF/

Answer (score 0):

Going by your comments under your question, @Tony_Henrich, in this situation I'd normally "fake" it by making the `border-left-color` of the smaller div equal to the two divs' `background-color`.  Then set `position: relative` and `left: -<border-width value>` on the smaller div so it overlaps the larger one.

Here's a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5Q3A5/

Comment: Same issue as what I noted below LukaszBorawski's answer. This will give you a 1 pixel gap where the borders intersect: http://jsfiddle.net/RWz4A/

Comment: I'm not sure that warrants a downvote.  The question was answered, but perhaps not in the prettiest way.  I believe that your posted solution is better, though, @Zhihao.

Comment: Sorry, you're right. I suppose I was just a bit exasperated to see it edited to add a jsFiddle with the same issue I had previously mentioned (twice). I'll remove the downvote.

Comment: ...I can't remove the downvote because it passed the time limit...I'll remove it if you edit the answer...:(

Comment: I can see how that might be frustrating. If it makes you feel better, I already had the jsfiddle made when I posted (before I saw your comment) but forgot to add it.